# Can you spend a portion of the balance of a cold storage wallet?

Tags: cold-storage

When you have a Bitcoin paper wallet, you have to send the entire balance out of the wallet if you want to spend a part of it, because the change will not be sent back to the wallet.  I have been unable to tell if there is a similar issue with Monero paper wallets. Is this different for Monero ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Monero the change is sent back to the same (public) address. Therefore, it would, in theory, be possible to spend a portion of the balance of a cold storage wallet. However, currently the binaries have no feature available to sign your transaction offline. A possible solution to this is compiling yourself and using [this](https://github.com/moneromooo-monero/bitmonero/commit/3c44e9fb6c1b57852d37780414ed6e42afc19afb) patch. From the patch:

> This change adds the ability to create a new unsigned transaction from a watch only wallet, and save it to a file. This file can then be moved to another computer/VM where a cold wallet may load it, sign it, and save it. That cold wallet does not need to have a blockchain nor daemon. The signed transaction file can then be moved back to the watch only wallet, which can load it and send
>   it to the daemon.
>
> Two new simplewallet commands to use it:
>   sign_transfer (on the cold wallet)
>   submit_transfer (on the watch only wallet)
>
> The transfer command used on a watch only wallet now writes an unsigned transaction set in a file called 'unsigned_monero_tx' instead of submitting the tx to the daemon as a normal wallet does. The signed tx file is called 'signed_monero_tx'.

It should be noted that merging the patch results in [merge conflicts](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4wrs72/if_i_transfer_100_xmr_to_an_offline_wallet_how_do/d6ad2t1), which you'd have to go through one by one.

The patch is [currently](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4wplta/update_from_moneromooo_includes_ring_ct/) being ported to Ring CT and therefore will likely be merged into master in conjunction with Ring CT.

Comment: It looks like this [was merged in](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/bba6af9064cb95596039f5a8f7ea460d3dedef0d) on Sep 27, 2016